# Can a Master student's thesis be kept indefinitely until the advisors have extracted everything the student has to give?

Tags: thesis, advisor, united-states

Is it legal for advisors in the US to prevent a student from graduating by *"suddenly, about a week before deadline, realizing that what the student was doing for the past few semesters is not what the advisors asked for and the student has to redo the project design all over..."* . I understand that the advisors might not be satisfied but shouldn't they notice this months ago?

Also, even after graduation, how much long are they, legally, allowed to ask for changes and feedback? Is it normal for professors to threaten the student pre but also post-graduation that they will take actions if the student doesn't do as asked?

I can elaborate if any questions arise but the main issue is that since they are occupied with their own issues (both professional, personal AND a mix of "personal aspirations" agenda interfering with the professional time they are paid to have with their students) and pay no attention to what I'm doing (while I constantly chase them to show them updates but they refuse even to look at my work, they literally closed my laptop's lid one day).

Comment: It is probably not a (criminal) legal issue unless the advisor is trying to use this leverage to extort money (or some other benefit) from the student. It is unlikely that a breach-of-contract lawsuit would work in this case; the school's lawyers would fight it strongly on principle (just a guess, not a lawyer). Your best recourse is probably through the school administrators--they might find a second professor to help you finish. You may want to rephrase the questions to get rid of the legal aspect, to get better answers.

Comment: @cactus_pardner what if the project might be used by a company that needs specific developing and therefore I am being used at their *unspoken* *unwilling* developer, that gets paid for a nickel compared to actual developers, and silently they make me readjust my results every time they don't fit their problem formulation? Of course this is just a *theory* , I am not there on their person-to-person meetings that they sacredly hold under closed doors and keep me out of, and of course they do not even credit me for....

Comment: Ah. Those aspects of the problem would be great to have in the question, though that desire to use your work seems at odds with ignoring you. :/

Comment: @cactus_pardner they take on a lot of projects and just use us as "running threads" (that's how I personally see it). For them a "thread" should not bother them until they have produced results on their own. If I knew there would be no guidance or actual research I would have stayed home and done the research myself without having to think about all this "gray" situation going around me.

Comment: "I understand that the advisors might not be satisfied but shouldn't they notice this months ago?" - it's up to the student as much as the advisor to ensure adequate communication between student and advisor. I can't see any legal recourse there.

Comment: @BryanKrause I literally had to force myself into making meetings happen and even then, they would ignore me and pretend they are listening while they were texting or just draw a blur and tell me "this is what you should do" , and when I went back with details to discus a solid idea about the "blur" they would tell me "ahhh this is implementation do not talk to me about this". The worst trick is that the meeting would be usually minutes before they "had to" leave the campus so when I got in the office they would be not paying attention , packing their things to leave , text, ignore me etc.

Comment: I'm not asking so much for legal recourse action but how to answer them to show them that I'm aware that they are breaking rules or abusing their rights and just let me graduate and stop harassing me post graduation.

Comment: There is no way for you to legally make a university graduate you unless they are breaking a law. You can talk to administrators for your graduate program or department, but note that in addition to having some care for you as a student they also have some care for their faculty members and department as a whole, so they are not necessarily going to be on your side. It kind of sounds like you left a lot of this until the last moment without doing something about the communication problems much earlier.

Comment: @BryanKrause I did A LOT, hence I got threatened with them forming a committee for my expulsion, another day it was to drop the thesis (so someone else would take over my work and do it) and do non-thesis. I was also told to avoid any written documentation (emails) so that *myself* would not get into trouble. (in those emails I was enlisting all the wrong reasons and what was happening and I guess they weren't pleased to have official paper trails about their behavior towards me)

Comment: Read around for people in bad circumstances on this stack. It does happen, but it's really hard for us to know what to advise in a given circumstance. If you had that bad of problems, you should have left long ago. Also keep in mind that *you* may be the problem without knowing it, and your bosses may want to post a question here about how to deal with their student who's been here forever, always works on their own project rather than what is assigned to them, and their progress is way below expectations but they want to graduate.

Comment: @BryanKrause You should take into consideration financial responsibility strings that these kind of people are aware of, especially with international students from third-world countries (the number of such cases is the majority). Saying just "leave" is not a valid choice for someone that is trying to do their best for a better future. You assume things like *" works on their own project "*, well I wish I had the freedom to do that but the notion of personal time does not exist for them and that's another issue that goes beyond the scope of this question I'm afraid.

Comment: Those are all reasons to attend reputable programs, get feedback from current students about programs as well as faculty, etc. Yes, abuses exist, but the type you are describing is far from the norm.

Comment: @BryanKrause Well every person I know loses their mind when I explain in detail what's happening but I think now I need people from academia to help me come up with an *elegant* way to get myself out of here without losing everything I've worked for. I asked for recommendations to look for a job which they said they would give but the minute they heard I found a Doc. program i was interested joining they went berserk mode on me telling me that I had told them I want a job(like it was set in stone)and that I don't know how to do research and should stay here do a PhD(I've been through a lot)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75862/discussion-between-bryan-krause-and-anna-k).

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly speaking a legal issue. There are generally internal university regulations that govern theses and dissertations, but enforcing them is not something that can be compelled through force of law.

There is normally a limit on the amount of time that can elapse for changes to be demanded, but this is entirely institution-dependent. Usually, though, any such period coincides with the conferral of the degree. At that point, the advisor and committee cannot ask for more changes.

All of that said, someone has committed derilection of duty in advising you. If there was a question about whether or not you were ready to defend, it should have been addressed before you wrote up the entire thesis and scheduled the defense. (It may have been the responsibility of a thesis committee, not the advisor, to make this decision. I don’t know without knowing more about the departmental regulations.)

Right now, I would talk to the other members of the committee, the chair of the graduate studies committee, and the chair of the department to figure out what can be done. This is not a good situation, and if your defense is scheduled for the near future, you may need to postpone it at least temporarily to avoid problems if your advisor is deadset on you redoing everything.

Comment: Days before the deadline week I had most figures ready, the outline written and was ready to type my thesis (it was a matter of finalizing my code to reflect EVERYTHING that we had discussed). They would NOT let me decide on a committee until I had made what they asked for (without giving me extra time, even if they had to submit a form to the grad school).The deadline passed,what I'm worried about is getting tricked into changing my design again.Oh, and everything involves the chairs (they are not *new in the neighborhood* they know well the system vs their fresh-to-the-system students)